# How to locate a file in a directory

Tags: command-line, find, locate

How can I locate a file using `locate` in `CentOS` under a specific directory from terminal?
Locate search the whole database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for that functionality in the output from `man locate` on CentOS 6.5, at least. But, you could get pseudo-functionality by changing a search term. For example, `locate cron` might produce too much output, but `locate '/var/log/cron'` would limit the results to those items in the `locate` database that match the search terms. Or, a pipe would work: `locate cron | grep '/var/log/'` Otherwise, use find: `find /path/to/search -name '*cron*'` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

`locate` does not seem to have an option to do this, but you can still search specific directories using one of the following:

- Use wildcards in your search. Example: `locate '*/directory/*filename*'`
- Use `grep` with `locate`. Example: `locate filename | grep /directory/`
- Use the `find` command. Example: `find /my/directory/ -name filename`. You can also restrict your search to directories or files by appending `-type d` or `-type f`. To find a file named 'myScript' in your home folder you could do this: `find ~/ -name myScript -type f`. This will search for a file (not directories) named exactly 'myScript' inside your home folder.